# Getting 404 not found when calling rest API using https ssl

Tags: rest, ssl, codenameone, tomcat8, tls1.2

Please can you help. I have created in Java a Rest API and exported the WAR file to my cloud Tomcat 8 server. I have been able to access and use it fine in my Codenameone app for months, using http://www.mydomain.co.uk:8080/MyProject/...

But i have now applied TLS\SSL to my server (purchased a Comodo certificate) and now, using my app or Postman get a connection timeout when i use the similar URL call https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject/...
The identical URL pasted in my browser also gives 'Connection took too long to respond'.
I have not made any changes to the Rest API project or the HTTP request headers i pass to it between the 2 calls. Why can't it be read now?

Disabling the firewall makes no difference. Using 443 ports makes no difference and using 8443 gives a 'Could not get any response'  in postman.

I have my 3rd party certificate correctly installed. I know this because in my browser if i run just "https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject" (no port) it downloads the WAR file. I can also view a test GIF file "https://www.mydomain.co.uk/test.gif" which is in my Tomcats /usr/share correctly, and the browser shows 'Secure' and i can see the correct certificate is being used. 
So i don't think this is a Tomcat ports/firewall problem or a certificate problem.
As my browser can download the WAR file using the same 1st half of the URL, then that must mean the location of the war file is OK.

It seems to be something around the actual calling of the Rest API which, as i said, works fine if i do "http://www.mydomain.co.uk:8080/MyProject/..."

Almost seems to be the way that Postman or the app calls the API. FYI, my only relevant request header i am passing it 'Content-Type' = 'application/json'.
Many thanks

**UPDATE 20/05/18**
Current position: 
When i issue the URL call to my rest api "https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject/some_path_params" (which works fine using http and 8080) i get a '404 Not Found' in all calling places (eg. Postman).

Looking at the apache2 error.log it says 'AH00128: File does not exist: /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/MyProject/some_path_params'.
This is correct in that the files don't exist, but this is because the endpoint is MyProject.

Does anyone know why it is trying to find the file represented in the URL, instead of calling the rest API and going into the java class that starts with '@Path("/some_path_params")' ?

Why won't Postman just run the Rest API when in https mode?

If I enter https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject, it does display the file structure, so I do have access to that directory.

BTW, when i restart the apache2, the logs confirm the TLS certificate is loaded correctly.

If it's relevant, i have included this in the web.xml of the Java project:

```
<security-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

My apache.conf has these sections:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_co_uk.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.mydomain.co.uk.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_co_uk.ca-bundle
 ServerName www.mydomain.co.uk
 Alias /MyProject "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/MyProject"

<Location />
Require all granted
</Location>
```

Comment: What do you see in the server logs? Catlina and the other logs? What do you see in the Codename One Network Monitor? If you can connect on https with no port to see a gif you shouldn't use a port for SSL.

Comment: An update. I restarted apache2 (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart) and the error changed. Then said 404 Not Found in Postman and Browser. This points to permissions to read the /webapps folder i think, but not sure. So stumbling around have added this line to apache2.conf file:  Alias /ProjectName "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ProjectName". I am now getting a 403 permissions error. I have added a basic <security-constraint> section to my application web.xml, but that hasn't made a difference. Logs show nothing relevant. Any help appreciated

Comment: Another change which hasn't made a difference is adding this to the apache2.conf:    <Directory "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/MyProject">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Allow from all
</Directory>             Wierdly, when i repeatedly send the Rest request using Postman, it usually says 403 Forbidden and sometimes 404 Not Found.

Comment: In apache.conf i set up "LogLevel debug" and noticed in my apache error.log that had permission errors. So have also put there "<Location />
Require all granted
</Location>" and this resolved those errors, but now the error log gives "AH00128: File does not exist" and points to the full URL request. Of course this doesnt exist as this is an @Path parameter inside the Rest class. Still stuck.

Comment: I once got a timeout in my codename one app running on the simulator and I was fiddling with the ConnectionRequest thinking something is wrong and I later realized it was due to using the server to send a mail before returning a response to the user. I delayed sending a mail and return a response immediately, this solved the timeout issue for me. By the way, I was using a PHP backend.

Comment: This is a problem between my java rest API project and the Tomcat https setup. Some conflict. Why is it never easy? Have updated main thread. Thanks

Comment: Make sure your unix permission in the directory where you deployed the web app are correct and match the user.

Comment: I have given 777 permissions on the directory but no affect. I created the fake sub directory it was after and it stopped erroring in the logs. Running the rest call no longer shows 404 but the index html page. So the war directory is accessible. But problem remains that this doesn’t trigger it to run the rest api. I think this is a problem with tomcat not reading my apps web.xml or (wasn’t there before) context.xml. Am fiddling with those files but no success yet. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem after 2 weeks of tweaking. My solution is against this call

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/87979638